# What is '"^[b" backward-word' When trying to configure ZSH?

Tags: zsh, escape-characters

I am on a MAC, and I am trying to figure out shortcuts for my ZSH running on Iterm2.

When I type bindkey in the shell, I see (among other mappings), the following:

```
"^[b" backward-word
"^[f" forward-word
```

I know ^ is Control key. But what if I press Ctrl + [ + f, it does not go a word forward.

What am I missing?

Comment: Odd; Ctrl+[ works for me in iTerm2.

Answer (score 5):

`^` is usually control, but `^[` actually means Escape or Alt (or meta, if you like emacs).

So you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> for those key combinations.

By default, Alt doesn't work on Mac terminals, but iTerm2 has a setting: "Option acts as [ ] Normal [ ] Meta [ ] +Esc". You want +Esc.

[image: Screenshot of iTerm2 Option key settings.]

Answer (score 2):

Actually `^[` is the Alt key. So in your case the terminal (Iterm2) uses Alt + b and Alt + f to go backwards and forwards a word. This is controled by your terminal and has nothing to do with zsh.

Comment: On a Mac, terminal emulators typically use the Escape key instead of Alt (Option), since the Option key has long been used for typing non-ASCII characters. (And in fact, `^[` is the ASCII representation for ASCII ESC.)

Answer (score 2):

To extend [mrb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162866/80886) answer:

Indeed `^[b` is <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> or (<kbd>Meta/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>).
You can display character literally by proceeding it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. In this case you will find the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

  `^B`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

  `^[b`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>

  `^[b`

Additionally you will find in zsh manual:

```
backward-word (ESC-B ESC-b) (unbound) (unbound)
    Move to the beginning of the previous word.
```

and similarly for `forward-word`:

```
forward-word (ESC-F ESC-f) (unbound) (unbound)
              Move to the beginning of the next word.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `^` notation is commonly used in the GNU world for control characters, where `^a` is Ctrl-A (ASCII 1 where A is ASCII 65).  In other words it is shorthand for "use the character 64 slots before this on".

The `ESC` key is ASCII 27 which is 64 steps before `[`, hence `^[` is shorthand for ESC.

In the GNU Emacs editor several modifier keys were used, CTRL, META and others.  For instance CTRL-f moves the cursor a character forward and META-f moves the cursor a word forward.

In order to accomodate the many keyboards without a META key, a convention of "ESC means that the next character is to be considered pressed with the META-key".  Therefore in GNU Emacs, pressing ESC-f moves the cursor a word forward.

Note that these days it is very rare that `Ctrl-[` gives an ESC character, but it may be lurking in some other Ctrl-combination.  For instance is `^^` still used in telnet sessions to escape to command mode, so it is useful to be able to find it.